# How to determine reason for slow response time for LWP::UserAgent on a particular page?

Tags: perl, lwp-useragent

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get('https://olms.dol-esa.gov/query/getYearlyData.do');
print $response->decoded_content;
```

The code takes upwards of two minutes to print out the results. Other web pages print out within a second or two. I'm curious to know why this page takes so long to load. How can I figure out what the problem is?

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with LWP. Try visiting that page in a regular web browser and looking at the response times in the browser's developer tools. It's probably just a poorly-built page, or it's generating massive amounts of data.

Comment: For me, the page takes a few seconds to load in a browser, and a few seconds using your code above. Seems to be pretty slow on the server side, not sure there's much more to it.

Comment: It loads in a couple of seconds in my browser but my script can take upwards of 2 minutes. Something else is at play. Also, I'm now noticiing about half the time I get an error:

SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.20.2/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 48, <DATA> line 1.

Comment: Other web pages on the same site (https://olms.dol-esa.gov/) or other sites ? If other site, it may be a DNS problem.

Comment: Just this site seems to be giving me problems.

Answer (score 2):

This hostname has serious DNS issues, see this [DNSviz analysis](http://dnsviz.net/d/olms.dol-esa.gov/WJJ24Q/). This means that "sometimes" you will have trouble resolving the hostname as an IP address. This may lead to timeouts.

Comment: Any idea how to at least make it fail fast if it can't resolve the name?

Comment: @Chomeh Use timeouts: https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#timeout  Or you can also do the name resolution yourself in advance of calling LWP::UserAgent. Also, why do you need to fail "immediately"? If you have high volume of things to check, doing them sequentially will always be a problem.

Comment: Cheers. The Oauth server became unavailable, but it took 10min for LWP to report 'Connection timed out' so I wasted a bunch of time checking other things. For some reason it's ignoring the configured timeout in my case.

Comment: A connection timeout is not a name resolution problem.